# Streaming device without HDMI?

Tags: usb, hdmi

*I hope that fits in this Exchange as it specifically deals with a hardware problem. That out of the way:*

My current TV is working properly except of all the HDMI slots. It’s not changeable and even if it were let’s take it as a condition for the following problem. I want a sort of streaming hub/device (like amazon fire TV stick - in fact I already have one), though using an adapter from HDMI to USB and using it through the USB port of the TV is rather dangerous according to online sources.

Is there any other cheap alternative to either amazon fire TV (which doesn’t use HDMI and still provides a decent quality including services like Netflix, Prime Video, etc.) or is there a safe way to use said stick without the HDMI slots?

Comment: I think you misunderstood how the Amazon Fire TV stick works. It plugs into HDMI for video, and USB but just for power. USB ports on TVs do not support video. They just support file transfers and act as a power supply for things like the Fire TV. If your TV has a USB Type-C port then that is an entirely different plug with a possibility that it supports video for some media devices.

Answer (score -1):

Using the USB port on TV is OK

It is never been dangerous enough although some reason such as:

- Electrical shock (many TV use two-pole plug without ground).
- The power only 0.5A only better TV use a 1A port.
- Compatibility issue.
- This port is not for charging :)

The dangerous warning sticking the amazon fire stick to a USB port because people thinking it could be powering the amazon firestick with less adaptor.

The most side effect of using the USB port on TV for powering the amazon firestick is when the TV is off the power is off too. **This without anything working on amazon is OK**.

**But if amazon firestick is updating the firmware and suddenly you turn off the TV you could brick the amazon firestick.**

But if you disable the auto-update it will be working fine. Unless your USB port can't recognize your device :)

Comment: I think you focused too much on the OP saying "using it through the USB port of the TV is rather dangerous" and did not actually answer their question.